# How to stop my program in raspberry with thread?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, raspberry-pi4

I have a project to build GUI for raspberry project thermocycler. I have some error in pushbutton GUI. I can start the thermocycler from pushbutton GUI, but can't to stop. When thermocycler is on, my GUI freeze. I will write my code below. If anyone have a solution for my error please. what is need use a threading?

my code

```
import sys
from PySide2 import *
from PySide2.QtGui import QPainter
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication)
from PySide2.QtCharts import QtCharts


from PySide2.QtGui import QPainter
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication)
from PySide2.QtCharts import QtCharts

from random import randrange
from functools import partial
import csv
import time
import math
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_ADS1x15
from datetime import datetime
file_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')

from ui_interface4 import 4
shadow_elements = { 
    "left_menu_frame",
    "frame_3",
    "frame_5",
    "header_frame",
    "frame_9"
}

temp_denat = 95
temp_anel = 55
temp_exten = 72
temp_refri = 4

heat_pin = 19 #pwm > GPIO 19 > LPWM
cool_pin = 18 #pwm > GPIO 13 > RPWM
pwm_fan = 12 #pwm > GPIO 12 > fan cooling
low_volt = 21 #digital > GPIO 21 > 3v3

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()

        self.ui.setupUi(self)
 
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint) 

        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
      
        self.shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
        self.shadow.setBlurRadius(20)
        self.shadow.setXOffset(0)
        self.shadow.setYOffset(0)
        
        self.ui.centralwidget.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)   

        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(":/icons/icons/pie-chart.svg"))

        self.setWindowTitle("PCR_2")

        QSizeGrip(self.ui.size_grip)

        self.ui.minimize_window_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.showMinimized())
        
        self.ui.close_window_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())

        self.ui.restore_window_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.restore_or_maximize_window())
        
        switch = False
        
        def Program_Run (switch):
            def suhu_c(R, Ro=100000.0, To=25.0, beta=3950.0):
                suhu = math.log(R / Ro)
                suhu /= beta
                suhu += 1.0 /  (To + 273.15)
                suhu = (1.0 / suhu)
                suhu -=273.15
                return suhu

            GPIO.setwarnings(False) #disable warning
            GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) #board GPIO
            GPIO.setup(heat_pin,GPIO.OUT) 
            GPIO.setup(cool_pin,GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.setup(pwm_fan,GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.setup(low_volt,GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.output(low_volt,GPIO.HIGH)
            adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115(address=0x49,busnum=1)
            
            GAIN = 2/3 
            t = 0
            rn = 100000
            pwm_val = 0

            print('channel-0 value')
            told = time.time()

            cool = GPIO.PWM(heat_pin,490) #490Hz
            heat = GPIO.PWM(cool_pin,490) #490Hz
            fan = GPIO.PWM(pwm_fan,490) #490Hz
            heat.start(0)
            cool.start(0)
            fan.start(0)
            while switch == True:
                range = time.time() - told
                bit = adc.read_adc_difference(0,gain=GAIN)
                voltage = (bit*6.144)/32768
                R = rn*((5*rn)-(voltage*2*rn))/((5*rn)+(voltage*2*rn))
                suhu = suhu_c(R)
            
                if suhu <= temp_denat:
                    pwm = 96
                    cool.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
                    heat.ChangeDutyCycle(pwm)
                    fan.ChangeDutyCycle(0)

                if suhu >= temp_denat:
                    pwm = 80
                    cool.ChangeDutyCycle(pwm)
                    heat.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
                    fan.ChangeDutyCycle(100)
                  
                if range >= 1.00:
                    print(t,' ADC bit:',round(bit),' bit', ',voltage: ',round(voltage,3),' volt','suhu', round(suhu,3), ' C','R:',round(R,3),'ohm')
                    t += 1
                    told = time.time()
                    
            while switch == False:
                
                break
                    
        def Start_Program():
            switch = True
            Program_Run (switch)
            
        def Stop_Program():
            switch = False
            Program_Run (switch)
        def moveWindow(e):

            if self.isMaximized() == False: #Not maximized
                if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:  
                    self.move(self.pos() + e.globalPos() - self.clickPosition)
                    self.clickPosition = e.globalPos()
                    e.accept()

        self.ui.header_frame.mouseMoveEvent = moveWindow

        self.show()

        for x in shadow_elements:
                ## # Shadow effect style
                effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
                effect.setBlurRadius(18)
                effect.setXOffset(0)
                effect.setYOffset(0)
                effect.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0, 255))  
                getattr(self.ui, x).setGraphicsEffect(effect) 

        self.ui.START_btn.clicked.connect(Start_Program)
        self.ui.CANCEL_btn.clicked.connect(Stop_Program)

    def restore_or_maximize_window(self):
        if self.isMaximized():
            self.showNormal()
            self.ui.restore_window_button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(u":/icons/icons/maximize-2.svg"))
        else:
            self.showMaximized()
            self.ui.restore_window_button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(u":/icons/icons/minimize-2.svg"))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clickPosition = event.globalPos()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `while` loops should never be used in the main UI thread unless it's guaranteed that they exit as soon as possible. Do some research on QThreads, as there are literally dozens of resources and posts about the topic. Also note that: 1. you should avoid excessive use of local functions, as they only make debugging unnecessarily difficult and complex; 2. "patching" of event handlers (like you did with `moveWindow`) is generally discouraged as it often causes silent errors; 3. you should always try to provide a [mre].

Comment: thank you. but are you have a suggestion for my while loop?
if while loop will move, I will move this loop to there?

Comment: Sorry but I already gave you the only suggestion I could provide (do research on QThreads), as your code is too convoluted and extended to be able to answer.